# Is it possible to use KVO to observer an CLLocation object?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-location, key-value-observing

My CLLocation object is located in a different object and one of my UI screens wants to update certain stats from that object, is it possible to use KVO to observe those changes for example, longitude and latitude.

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed.  Using KVO is a common technique when you have an object maintaining a value and need to be notified of changes in multiple places.  Seems like a reasonable question and use of KVO to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically I wouldn't rely on KVO with any Cocoa object or value that it isn't explicitly documented to work for. Even if it worked, you couldn't rely on its continuing to do so.

But CLLocationManager has a delegate (CLLocationManagerDelegate) to which all changes are reported, so why aren't you using that? Or if some other object is the delegate already, why can't you arrange for it to send your object a message, or at least post a notification? This sounds like any other elementary object communication problem.

Comment: So what do you recommend, I'm already using the CLLocation manager delegate for the main view. I can use NSNotificaiton or create my own KVO properties.

Comment: Either one sounds great. KVO has the obvious advantage that KVO-compliant changes are reported to the observer automatically. But personally I regard KVO management as clumsy; whereas now that we've got `addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:`, notifications are almost downright elegant. But don't let my personal biases influence you! :)